# Changing bar plot style

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I achieve the same font style and plot style as in the screenshot?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the font looks a bit like `\bfseries\sffamily`, and you can define your own `bar cycle list` for the colors.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{curlyblue}{RGB}{39,26,115}
\definecolor{curlygreen}{RGB}{48,172,140}   
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
    {black,fill=curlyblue,mark=none},
{black,fill=curlygreen,mark=none},
{black,fill=yellow,mark=none},
}, }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.25,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the legend inside the plot, set `legend columns` to one and make the plot a bit larger.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{curlyblue}{RGB}{39,26,115}
\definecolor{curlygreen}{RGB}{48,172,140}   
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
    {black,fill=curlyblue,mark=none},
{black,fill=curlygreen,mark=none},
{black,fill=yellow,mark=none},
}, }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.25,
    legend style={at={(0.75,0.95)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    ylabel={\#participants},
    symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @NaveganTeX Yes. You need to make the plot a bit larger to fit it.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks fantastic!